# JQuery and Rails :: Is it possible to replace HTML with the result of a JavaScript Function?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm fairly new to Rails and JavaScript and am having a bit of an issue with getting an Ajax call to update my JSTree element in my DOM.

I know the Ajax call is working because I can inspect the @folders instance variable and see all the entries.

For some reason though, with the code below, my JSTree element isn't getting its HTML replaced after the AJAX call.

The response that comes back from the server is literally the text contained in my **my_jserb_file.js.erb** file.

I guess I thought that when that buildMyJStree() function got ran in **my_jserb_file.js.erb**, that it would return the HTML and I could in turn use that variable to replace the HTML of the #treeViewDiv element.  Obviously that doesn't work though.

Can someone school me and let me know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks for your time.

---

**myView.html.haml**

```
%a.btn{id: 'open-test-data-directory'}
#treeViewDiv
```

---

**application.js**

```
$(document).on('click', '#open-test-data-directory', function() {
  $.ajax({
  method: "GET",
  url: "/fire_ajax"
})
```

---

**routes.rb**

```
get '/fire_ajax', to: 'ajax#go'
```

---

**ajax_controller.rb**

```
def go
    @folders = directory_hash("/home/jeffrey/Documents/Ruby_Workspace/")

    respond_to do |format|
        format.js {render :my_jserb_file}
    end
end
```

---

**my_jserb_file.js.erb**

```
function buildMyJStree(){
return $("#treeViewDiv").jstree({ 
    'core' : {
        'data' : @folders,
        'themes' : {
            'name' : 'proton'
            }
        }
   });
}

var myTree = buildMyJStree();

$("#treeViewDiv").html(myTree);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are generating JS on the backend, but you haven't instructed your Ajax call to execute the returned js. You can do this by setting `dataType: 'script'` in your Ajax call.

Comment: thanks for the response.  I gave that a shot, but unfortunately nothing changed.  I'm still receiving a text/javascript response from the server, which isn't being executed by the browser.

Any other ideas?

Comment: If you take the returned JS response, and paste it into the console, does it work or throw an error? I just noticed the `@folders` variable in your js.erb file isn't inside a `<%= %>`, so I would expect the @ symbol to throw an error. Sometimes if it fails it does so silently, and you can't find out until you paste it into the console.

Comment: DVG, you were correct.  The prob was that my folders variable was not being retrieved properly.  Once I wrapped it in the erb identifiers, then it came through.

One note though, I ended up having to do this, in order to get JSTree to build the tree. 

   `'data' : <%= @folders.to_json.html_safe %>,`

Not sure this is the best/correct way though.  

Thanks for all your help!